# How to change navbar background color after page has scrolled down

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a fixed navbar on a bootstrap project and on the landing page of the website, I have made the background of the navbar transparent. When the website scrolls down, I want the navbar background to change back to black. I am using bootstrap. An example of what I want can be seen in the nabber at :

http://ironsummitmedia.github.io/startbootstrap-agency/

I am a new coder, so I apologize for any mistakes in the code formatting.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>


<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <title>Youth  |  Society</title>
    <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="design.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    </head>


<body>
    <header>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">

          <a href="#" class="navbar-brand"><img src="1.png"></a>
          </div>


          <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">

            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>


          </button>

          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">

              <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Who are we</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Volunteer</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>

          </div>
         </div>
    </div>
        </header>


    <div class="page1"> 
    <div class="landing">
      <div class="container">
        <h1>Peel's YES</h1>
        <p>Welcome To Peel's Youth Engagement Society</p>
      </div>
<div class="topics">
      <div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <h3>Learn</h3>
            <p>Get to know more about YES, who we are, and what we do.</p>

          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <h3>Volunteer</h3>
            <p>Find out how you can get involved! YES strives to prove YOUth with unique opportunities and experiences.</p>

          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <h3>Educate</h3>
            <p>Read about the themes that YES has supported in the past</p>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

</body>

</DOCTYPE>
```

CSS:

```
.navbar-header {
    display: inline;
}

.navbar{
    background: transparent;
    background-color: transparent;
    border-color: transparent;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .navbar {
        background-color: black;

    }
}


.navbar-toggle{
    margin-top: -50px;


}

.navbar .nav > li > a {
    color:  black;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .navbar .nav > li > a {
        color:white;

    }
}
.navbar {

    padding-top:15px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;

}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .navbar {
        padding-top:0px;
        padding-bottom: 0px;

    }
}

.navbar a {

  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;  
}

.navbar li{

    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    display: inline;

}

.navbar img {
    max-height: 50px;
    margin-top: -20px;

}


/*      P A G E  1      */




.landing {
    padding-top:140px;
    background-image:url(mainpage1.JPG);
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    height: 760px;
}

.landing h1 {
    text-align: center;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 70px;  
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.landing p {
    text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #000;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}
.topics{

    background: #eeeeee;
    padding-right:40px;
    margin-top: 340px;
    text-align: center;
}

.topics h3{
    font-size: 18px;
}

.topics p{
    font-size: 18px;
}


/*      P A G E  2      */


.page2 {
    height:760px;

}

.page2 h3{
    text-align: left;
    margin-top: 100px;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/AngularJR/j68kf0j7/3/)** to view.

I made a change the have the shade color of the nav also show in smaller screens if this helps you.

If you come across this post and view the Fiddle, make sure you make the view frame lager.

This navbar effect is for large screens. (768 px Plus) **[Large view FIDDLE here.](https://jsfiddle.net/AngularJR/j68kf0j7/3/embedded/result/)**

You can change when the effect happens as you scroll from the top here.

```
var docElem = document.documentElement,
    header = document.querySelector( '.navbar-default' ),
    didScroll = false,
    changeHeaderOn = 200;
```

The background color is changed by this here

```
.navbar-default.navbar-shrink {
padding: 10px 0;
background-color: #222567;
background: rgba(70,10,200,0.9);
```

And the background color is first set by this here.

```
@media(min-width:768px) {
.navbar-default {
padding: 25px 0;
border: 0;
/*  background-color: transparent; */
background: rgba(70,10,200,0.4);
-webkit-transition: padding .3s;
-moz-transition: padding .3s;
transition: padding .3s;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing @AngularJR , I'm fading the shrink version with CSS, but when I scroll back up the fade doesn't apply again.

Answer (score 2):

There are many scripts out there for animating things on scroll. Honestly, it really depends on that you want to do. Here is a jQuery script that shows the basics. It simply adds a class to `navbar` (or whatever you want) once the visitor has scroll past a certain point. On the class, in this case `shrink`, I usually add transition easing to the class which makes things transition nicely when adding/removing the class.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 200){ // Set position from top to add class
        $('.navbar').addClass("shrink");
    } else {
        $('.navbar').removeClass("shrink");
    }
});
```